# PHP include() does not load config.php

Tags: php

I am trying to make a simple script, but when I try to include the config file, it wont load.
Here is my code-

```
<?php
$config = include("http://MyWebSite/config.php");
$mysql = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
if (!$mysql) { die(mysql_error()); }
$data = mysql_select_db($database);
if (!$data) { die(mysql_error()); }
?>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you didn't mean to load "config.php" via HTTP. Try simply include("config.php") assuming it's in the same directory as the script.

Comment: If you use `require` instead of `include`, you don't have to guess whether or not your file is loaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/config.php');
```

Also, don't assign it to a variable. You simply want to include the file in the script.

Answer (score 1):

you should try like that

```
<?php
include("config.php");
?>
```

Because in normal server setting you are not allowed directly include files remotely.

Comment: @Basic: include **has** return values, see [Example #4 + #5](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) and the paragraph above.

Answer (score 1):

1) include doesn't return anything
2) include whole url must be enabled by server

Comment: 1) See [Example #4 + #5](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) and paragraph above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the path to the file is correct. The following code will look for config.php in the same directory as the script that you are running:

```
include('config.php');
```

If that does not work you can look at the error logs or turn on error reporting with the following code:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
include('config.php');
```

The error message should now show you where it is looking for the file. The error will look something like the following:

```
Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'config.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /path/to/your/script.php on line 4
```

The above message states that it could not find config.php at any of the following locations:

```
 /path/to/your/ 
 /usr/share/pear/
 /usr/share/php/
```